# Would like to add a "leaderboard" (custom field) to a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, user-meta

I've made a custom post type called a "Workout" that has an associated "leaderboard" just some text that has the top scores for the day. I'm trying to flush out the following use case:

> In the evening, when all workouts have been completed, any of 10 coaches has a common password or a custom query string that they append to the end of the post (typing ?pw=12345 probably wouldn't work). They might be able to log in as type "coach", but not admins. When they type this, they can edit or update the leaderboard for the post (on the same page or on  a new one). This whole process is simple, easy and the leaderboard appears in the upper right on each post.

Any pointers would be great. Adding a custom field is easy, but any thoughts on how to make the update work (or plugins) would be excellent.

Comment: I don't 100% understand the plan. If you used a User Roles plugin. You could create a role "Coaches", allow Coaches to create the post type Workout. If there is a numeric meta value to the post, you could then look up all the values from that meta on post type Workout authored by 'Coach A', and then compare it to 'Coach B' (or however your system works.) With a leaderboard, I would probably grab all the coaches that posted within the competition time frame, map them to an array, use a sort method to get rankings. It depends on the strategy you put in place how easily you can get ranking list.

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far please. Plugin recommendations are off topic.

Comment: @BradDalton, there is no relevant code yet. I'm asking how one would architect this solution.

Comment: @OnethingSimple, sorry for any confusion. This is much more simple -- just one extra text field for the custom post ('workout'), which is easy to add. The hard part for me is visualizing how a pool of users could update that field easily. These are very non-technical users and the owner wants to give them minimal control over, posts, etc.